# Error with Intalio Designer-generated code

Tags: wsdl

I always have this kind of error whenever I validate my project in intalio,

```
The 'body' element defined here is undefined for the SOAP namespace. The only valid element is "fault".

The 'Process' port type specified for the 'process_flowAndUsersForPortTypeProcessPlkServiceBinding' binding is undefined. Check the 'Process' port type name and ensure it is defined.
```

What should I do to troubleshoot this error? Every script in the the file the error specifies were automatically generated by the Intalio Designer. Do I have configuration problems? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you defined a process for which a message is sent to a pool which has no concrete end point (there is a port type but no port). You need to specify a binding for the port type so the endpoint can be resolved.

You will have better answers on the Intalio community site.